# Placeholder text fallback event issue in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, placeholder

I have a text field with placeholder text as "First Name" so when user clicks on the field
the text disappears and it allows him to type in the text

HTML

```
  <input class="fname" type="text" placeholder="First Name"/>
```

JS

```
function placeHolderFallBack() {
if("placeholder" in document.createElement("input")) {  
    return;     //In chrome it comes here
}else { 
    // works fine in IE8,FF 
    }
```

So basically the above code doesn't work in chrome, any ideas ?

Comment: Your function [seems fine in Chromium](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/m3qXa/1/) (or at least the test method is fine); so the problem is likely elsewhere. Can you post a [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/), so we can follow what's going on?

Comment: What is the question? There is no problem with that code and you can easily see it.

Comment: @Esailija It's a valid question the placeholder doesn't disappear in Chrome, it remain in the field as watermark.

Comment: Here's the demo .. http://jsfiddle.net/XQcYu/

Comment: Your demo doesn't have any code for chrome or browsers that support placeholder, again, what is the problem

Comment: problem is when i click or focus on text field the overlay text "first name" disappears which is what i want, but this doesn't happen in chrome (i.e text doesn't disappear)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In chrome and safari the placeholder attribute works on keyup. It disappears when you start typing.

Still if it is really needed try this approach

DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/NL2Dr/2/

```
var ttext;

$('input').focus(function(){
    ttext = $(this).attr('placeholder');            
    $(this).removeAttr('placeholder');
});
$('input').blur(function(){
    $(this).attr('placeholder', ttext);
});
```

Comment: thanks dipaks but if there are 5-10 diff text fields it wudn't be that helpful to have above code i guess.

Comment: updated the fiddle. You can achieve the same with multiple fields

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Dipaks, but it doesn't work when you deactivate and then reactivate Chrome while one of the inputs is selected. Also I think it needs a little improvement performance-wise. Here is the revised version:

```
$('input:text, textarea').each(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('placeholder', $this.attr('placeholder'))
         .focus(function(){$this.removeAttr('placeholder');})
         .blur(function(){$this.attr('placeholder', $this.data('placeholder'));});
});
```